# How to handle cascading deletes on inherited tables?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-5, cascade, ef-model-first

I've run into a problem with ON DELETE CASCADE when using inherited tables.

I've got the following tables (model first) 
[image: database model]

Now if I want to delete an entry in Entity1.

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
   var first = ctx.Entity1Set.First();
   ctx.DeleteObject(first);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Simple... But SaveChanges throws the following exception.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   FK_EntityA_inherits_BaseEntity". The conflict occurred in database
>   "MyDB", table "dbo.BaseEntitySet_EntityA", column 'Id'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

How do I fix this?

---

### UPDATE

I noticed a difference between how VS2010 and VS2012 model designer outputs SQL.

**VS2010**:

```
-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityA'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseEntitySet_EntityA]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityA_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityB'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseEntitySet_EntityB]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityB_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO
```

Notice **ON DELETE NO ACTION**

**VS2012**

```
-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityA'
ALTER TABLE [BaseEntitySet_EntityA]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityA_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityB'
ALTER TABLE [BaseEntitySet_EntityB]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityB_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO
```

Notice **ON DELETE CASCADE**

That's rather significant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the Visual Studio 2010 ADO entity designer which causes incorrect SQL to be generated.

**VS2010:**

```
-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityA'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseEntitySet_EntityA]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityA_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityB'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseEntitySet_EntityB]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityB_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO
```

Notice **ON DELETE NO ACTION**

**VS2012**

```
-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityA'
ALTER TABLE [BaseEntitySet_EntityA]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityA_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Id] in table 'BaseEntitySet_EntityB'
ALTER TABLE [BaseEntitySet_EntityB]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityB_inherits_BaseEntity]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id])
    REFERENCES [BaseEntitySet]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO
```

Notice **ON DELETE CASCADE**

After applying these changes to the database I could delete without problems.